# What does the actor say?

Tags: spoken-english

I hope it is  allowed to ask this question on this forum. What does Gerard Butler say from the beginning of the video till 0:15?
https://youtu.be/T4AM_I5b1CM
Please don't ban me. If this is the wrong section, I  will post my question where it belongs.

Comment: pagan blessing and book of pagan blessings. But there is something I can't understand that is mumbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerald Butler says

> Don't talk to me about that pagan blessing. Has anybody told you Roring's (?) comment about the pagan blessing? When Hilmar was looking through the book of blessings, he went "Oh *[laughs]* oh wrong one *[laughs]* oh shit! I just put a curse on the movie!

For the back story see [Wrath of Gods](https://wrathofgods.com/). A lot had gone wrong already, and then

> After moving the whole company to the town of Hofn on the east coast of Iceland, the production was sent off with a Pagan blessing, performed by Hilmar Orn Hilmarsson, a composer and the high priest of the ancient Norse Asatru religion. There he called upon Odin, Thor and Baldur to protect the production. Right at the end of the ceremony Sturla fell and hit his head on the rocky beach. His Icelandic co-workers eagerly shared the old Icelandic superstition that falling at the start made for a prosperous journey. Two hours later the Pagan priest himself slipped on the rocks at the Hofn beach and broke three ribs. The story of Beowulf & Grendel includes the introduction of Christianity into a Pagan society and the inevitable struggle between the two religions. That Saturday night, some of the producers started wondering if the Pagan ritual had angered the wrong god. Gerard Butler and the rest of the cast and crew started joking about the “curse” but as time went on the jokes gained a more serious undertone.

And in the interview, Gerald Butler says the 'blessing' was actually a 'curse'.

Comment: Thank you so much, Weather Vane :)